# If an primitive type is considered an object then is it considered an array?

Tags: javascript

When we retrieve the descriptor of an primitive type like the example below this paragraph we specify an integer as the object(which becomes the value of the property as well) and we specify the key as well which is '0'. Now because we specified an integer as the key would this mean that from ES2015 onwards, the primitive type is considered an array?

```
var e = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor([50], 0);
```

value of 'var e':

```
{
       configurable: false,
       enumerable: true,
       value: 50,
       writable: false
}
```

Or in the next example we pass in a string value:

```
var e = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor("hello", 0);
```

Which yields somewhat different results:

```
configurable: false
enumerable: true
value: "h"
writable: false
```

Now if we pass in a string it is treated as an array as well. But it appears that only the first character is being preserved as the value. Why does this happen as well?

Comment: Primitive values are **not** objects. In some situations, for example with a string primitive, a String object instance is automatically created around the primitive. But, again, primitives are not objects.

Comment: array isnt a primitive, its a type of object

Comment: In low level languages (C/C++), a `String` is simply an array of bytes. In JavaScript and other higher level languages, `String` is an array of bytes with a sort of wrapper around it to give it more functionality. Plus these two things are crucial for text manipulation which is used in countless places across the internet.

Comment: `"hello"[0] === "h"`

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c']` stores the data `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}`, similarly `"abc"` also stores `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}` --- so running `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` with a `0` will give you the property with key `0`, which is the first element for an array and first character for a string

Comment: @skara9 that array's aren't objects is the elephant in the room here. However, it seems as if an primitive type is being treated like one, atleast if  it's being passed as an argument to methods like getOwnPropertyDescriptor().

Comment: @skara9 So then technically speaking, in javascript a string is considered an array?

Comment: No, arrays are definitely objects.

Comment: No, a JavaScript string is not an array. When it's used as if it were, the language implicitly constructs a String instance, with indexes for all the character positions of the string primitive, and those work as with any other object property reference via `[ ]`.

Comment: @Pointy Javascript docs definition for 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor()': "In ES2015, a non-object first argument will be coerced to an object at first."

Comment: the `String` class is different from the primitive `string` - js just tends to coerce between them in many cases, for example, in `Object.entries('abc')`, the `string` `'abc'` is converted to an object `new String('abc')`

Comment: @handsome-and-SKINNY right, so therefore: there are such things as non-objects, and a string is one of them.

Comment: @Pointy So again, going back to your first comment. You're implying that in "some situations" (such as getOwnPropertyDescriptor()) an SEPERATE object or rather array is created to represent that primitive type. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In some languages that's called "auto-boxing": a temporary object, or "box", is constructed around the primitive value. Same thing happens for numbers.

Comment: @Pointy However, when this string is turned into an seperate object, is  this explicitly a random array or is this object created from the wrapper String class?

Comment: It's a String instance. When necessary, it's `string -> String`, `number -> Number`, `boolean -> Boolean`. Really only String and Number classes have useful prototype methods. Arrays are a totally different class of object. The `[ ]` operator works on *any* kind of object in basically exactly the same way.

Comment: @Pointy So if im not mistaken other primitive values, lets say: getOwnPropertyDescriptor(true, 0), in this case 'true' will be coerced into a seperate Boolean object. And what should be the key to access that 'true' value?

Comment: The Boolean `.valueOf()` method returns the primitive boolean value. Generally, doing that sort of thing explicitly in real code is not the best idea. The Boolean `.valueOf()` is somewhat unusual because *generally* `.valueOf()` returns a number.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, what i actually was asking was: if Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) would allow parameter 'obj' to be another primitive value besides string. Because it seems getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) ONLY returns a descriptor if 'obj' is a string OR array. Inputs  such as: "44, true, false" as argument makes the method return undefined.

Comment: @handsome-and-SKINNY yes because Number instances and Boolean instances have no "own" properties, while String instances do.

Answer (score 1):

When we try to get the descriptor for primitives, they are first converted to an object form [as per the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor):

> 20.1.2.8 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ( O, P )
>
> When the getOwnPropertyDescriptor function is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let obj be ? ToObject(O).
> 2. Let key be ? ToPropertyKey(P).
> 3. Let desc be ? obj.[GetOwnProperty].
> 4. Return FromPropertyDescriptor(desc).

and so any information we get from the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` will tell us nothing about the primitive itself, it only tells us something about the properties of the object that comes rolling out of the [toObject](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toobject) step.